# Initial directory for OpenFileDialog vs FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

When I use the OpenFileDialog to pick a file, it remembers the last visited directory so that when I go back to the dialog, it starts in that location by default.

But the FolderBrowserDialog does not start at that location and instead starts at the specified RootFolder.

So I would like to know where does OpenFileDialog store the last visited path so I can retrieve it and use it as the default location for FolderBrowserDialog.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the property `RestoreDirectory` of the `OpenFileDialog` is set to false. Then you can check the value of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get the most recent one. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the top-most folder that will appear within the tree view of the dialog box, set the `RootFolder property`, which takes a member of the `Environment.SpecialFolder` [enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2).

So the only way to keep the last used directory is to set the `SelectedPath` property yourself. Store the last selected directory by the user in a field/configuration settings and then restore it before opening the `FolderBrowserDialog`